# What is the next such palindrome

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence of  palindromic numbers where each term is defined as the smallest  palindromic number with **exactly** k distinct palindromic prime factors (to avoid ambiguity, here I mean a palindromic number whose prime factors are **ALL** also palindromic numbers.). The sequence begins: $2$,$6$,$66$,$6666$:

- $2$
- $6$=$2$.$3$
- $66$=$2$.$3$.$11$
- $6666$=$2$.$3$.$11$.$101$

What is the next term after $6666$,does the next term exist ?. I have checked palindromes up to $10^9$( But I know that if there are infinitely many primes of the form $10000....00001$,then this sequence is absolutely infinite.). So what is the next term ?

Comment: Where does this come from? It looks like a contest, maybe ProjectEuler?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut,no, it just come to my head : D

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of: [Such a beautiful sequence of palindromic numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1499843/318073).

Answer (score 0):

From a relatively quick test, the recurrent sequence
$$a_0=6,\quad
a_{n+1}=a_n\cdot (10^{2^{n-1}}+1), \quad n\ge3$$
are of numbers with $2^n$ repeated 6's.

I have no answer if there something that can generate  other lenghts, like 666 or 66666, etc...

Comment: I mean any palindrome, not just restricted to string of digit $6$