# Palindromes with distinct palindromic prime factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, palindrome

Imagine the sequence of palindromic numbers where each term is defined as the smallest square-free palindromic number with no other prime factors but the n distinct palindromic prime factors. The sequence begins:

- $2$
- $6=2\cdot3$
- $66=2\cdot3\cdot11$
- $6666=2\cdot3\cdot11\cdot101$

What is the next term? Does the next term exist? I know that if there are infinitely many primes of the form $100000....000001$,then this sequence is definitely infinite, but it doesn't mean the infinitude of this sequence depends entirely on the infinitude of primes of the form $100000....000001$. I've checked palindromes up to $10^{10}$ now. So,what is the next term ?

Comment: This one? https://oeis.org/A087331

Comment: @mvw, no it's a totally different sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understood the definition of the sequence, but
$$
334\,826\,628\,433=11\cdot101\cdot353\cdot919\cdot929
$$
seems to be the next term.

Comment: Aguirre, I meant the smallest square-free palindrome with exactly n distinct palindromic prime factors and no other prime factors but that palindromic prime factors : D

Comment: Aguirre, would you like to submit it to oeis, I would like to see your name there ! : )

Comment: It already is. Submit it yourself. After all, you defined i and I only found the fifth term.

Comment: But I've found only the trivial ones, while you've found the nontrivial one : )

Comment: The merit should go to Mathematica.

Comment: It was never submitted to the OEIS?